# Oracle APEX Region auto refresh internal error

Tags: oracle, refresh, oracle-apex

I am new to oracle apex. When trying to do the region auto refresh in APEX,  as several docs suggested, I used the below method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   setInterval("jQuery('#STATIC_REGION_ID').trigger('apexrefresh');", 5000);
</script>
```

Everything worked fine but after quite a long period time (maybe SSO timeout)   there are pop-up windows said "internal error".

Can anyone give me a hand for this? Or how can i check the server log to see more details for this internal error?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Could be related to SSO timeout - your code works for me (as long as you specify the correct static region ID). There's a known issue with Interactive Reports in general which has similar behaviour (when session auth times out, ajax calls e.g. some of the Actions menu options result in internal errors).

Comment: Thanks jeffrey. Is there any other good way to do the region auto refresh?

Comment: One method is to use `<meta http-equiv="refresh">`, e.g. http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2006/10/25/apex-tip-page-auto-refresh/

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. Very appreciated your help. Although I am trying to do a region auto refresh, this is also helpful.

Comment: Well, refreshing the whole page *does* refresh the region :)

Comment: I'm quite sure that @JeffreyKemp is correct and the session has timed out, and the refresh is "failing". Refreshing the page will work too, but the session will time out eventually as well. What did you configure for time-out etc?

Comment: @Tom, yes, except the difference is that if the whole page is refreshed, SSO should work properly (e.g. redirect to a login page). The problem is with ajax calls to the db when the session has timed out, where the user doesn't get a chance to re-login.

Comment: What apex version is this in? I saw the thread and screenshot on OTN too. I can't reproduce this exactly, what am I missing? I don't think the authentication scheme is an issue. I simply made an IR page, set the max session length to 30 seconds and ran the refresh code on the page. I don't get an alert box with "internal error" on 4.2 but rather JS errors. On apex.oracle.com I get an alert with "your session expired".

Comment: @Tom, I am with Apex 4.2.5.00.08. Our apex application introduced the oracle SSO together.  After the SSO timeout, the apex app with region auto refresh feature will throw the internal error.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that I use, is to create a dynamic action to refresh the region (or classic report) which is fired by a custom event. 
First we need to create de dynamic action, and defined it like this:

[image]

Here we're setting the conditions on which the dynamic action will be fired. In this case it will be fired by a custom event triggered from the document itself.

Then we define the action to be ejecuted in this case a refresh:

[image]

And finally we select the type of element to be refreshed, in this case a region and then from the drop down list select the actual region.

[image]

Once the dynamic action is created all we need to do is fire the event, in javascript this can be done with this code:

```
function callMe(){
    $.event.trigger('theEvent'); /*Note that the event name is case sensitive*/
}
```

That will be all, I use this method to refresh mostly classic reports but it can be used in several situations. Given your description of the problem, it's possible that the 'apexrefresh' event does not handle all the nuances of refreshing a region (and the connections involved), that's why I'd recommend to let apex do it entirely with this method.

Comment: Thanks Typo for the detailed reply. I am wondering where I can put the firing event code "$.event.trigger('theEvent');" in. I tried to put this kind of code in the page attribute that "Execute when Page Loads " part and the region footer but no luck with them.

Comment: @AnneLiu in the page definition, on the "Function and Global Variable Declaration" section you can create a function containing the code. Then you can call it as necessary.

Comment: @AnneLiu also, it wouldn't have much sense to fire a refresh action on page load.

Comment: @AnneLiu I don't get it, I answered your question?